# combining arrays of different shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

I have 2 arrays that I would like to combine into a single array.
the first array looks like this:

```
array_a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

the second array looks like this:

```
array_b = [[2, 4, 8, 16, 32], [3, 9, 27, 81, 243], [4, 16, 64, 256, 1024],
           [5, 25, 125, 625, 3125]]
```

I would like the combined result to look something like this:

```
array_c = [[1,2],[1,4],[1,8],[1,16],[1,32],[2,3],[2,9],[2,27],[2,81],
           [2,243],[3,4],[3,16],[3,64],[3,256],[3,1024].....etc.]
```

I have been struggling with this for a day and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you want to happen with `5`? Is it just ignored?

Comment: sorry array_b[2] and array_b[3] are included. It was to tedious to write so i ommited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way you could do it with just for loops

```
for x in range(min(len(array_a), len(array_b))):
    for b in array_b[x]:
        array_c.append([array_a[x], b])
```

I had to add the extra min since there are five elements in the first array and only four arrays in the second

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a not too difficult list comprehension:

```
In []:
[(x, z) for x, y in zip(array_a, array_b) for z in y]

Out[]:
[(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 8), (1, 16), (1, 32), (2, 3), (2, 9), (2, 27), (2, 81),
 (2, 243), (3, 4), (3, 16), (3, 64), (3, 256), (3, 1024), (4, 5), (4, 25),
 (4, 125), (4, 625), (4, 3125)]
```

As there are only `4` elements in `array_b`, `5` in `array_a` is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a cleaner way of doing this, but this should work.

```
array_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array_b = [[2, 4, 8, 16, 32], [3, 9, 27, 81, 243], [4, 16, 64, 256, 1024], [5, 25, 125, 625, 3125]]

array_c = list()
for a, bs in zip(array_a, array_b):
    array_c += [[a, b] for b in bs]

print(array_c)
```